# Can formula field can be dependent on another field

Tags: apex, formula-field

Can we have one formula field which only can be evaluated based on another custom field. Like i want formula to be evuluate only when other filed has true value.

Comment: Please clarify what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, thanks for looking into this. What i had  tried was making formula field and dependent on other bollean custom field on same object, but didnt able to get that earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulas **always** evaluate, even if they may evaluate to a null value. Generally speaking, if you want to be "dependent" on another field, you'd do something like this:

```
IF(Other_field__c, value_when_true, null)
```

Comment: congratulations for reaching 151k .I really appreciate it.